# How to solve BigInteger incorrect result?

Tags: c#

I am doing some simple statistic stuff and need to compute sums of big numbers, I am using `System.Numerics.BigInteger`

for instance I am using `742^4`

## with c# I get

[image]

## with Excel I get this:

[image]

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of var use BigInteger, otherwise it will multiply ints before assigning to BigInteger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger xx = 742;
System.Numerics.BigInteger right = xx * xx * xx * xx;
```

xx is getting typed as an int, then it's multiplied and overflows, then it's stuffed into a BigInteger.  Got to start with a big integer from the beginning.